# css3 from squared image to trapezoid without x rotation

Tags: css, rotation, css-transforms, skew, distortion

I'm trying to transform a square div with a background image to a trapezoid.

I would like to make it in 2D, pretty much the same way the "Distort" tool of Photoshop does.

Basically, all I want is to narrow the top side of the square and get the image to be deformed accordingly.

The 3D transformation "seems" to do the trick:

```
transform: rotateX(30deg);
```

It works for most use cases but not all of them.
Indeed, It is a 30deg rotation of the square that "looks" like a trapezoid when seen from the front/back side but is remains a 30° rotated square when seen from any other side.

What I want is to get an actual trapezoid. I want the squared image to be distorted in a 2D way so that the shape and image are actually changed, with no rotation involved.

I tried this and it worked in terms of shape (trapezoid):

```
border-style: solid;
height: 0;
border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
border-width: 0 100px 100px 100px;
```

But then I can't replace the red area with a background-image that would follow the distortion. Which defeats my purpose.
Any attempt I tried gets the picture to remain undeformed.

Is there any css/html5/javascript trick that would achieve what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the effect by applying a 3D transform on a pseudo-element (on which you also set the `background-image`) and making sure it's flattened in its original plane - that of its parent. This means that if you want to rotate something in 3D, you have to rotate the parent.

**Step #1**: create a square `div`, add a pseudo (or a child) that has the exact same dimensions and set the `background-image` on this pseudo.

```
div {
    display: grid; /* makes pseudo stretch all across */
    width: 28em; /* whatever edge value we want */
    aspect-ratio: 1; /* make it square */
    /* just to highlight div boundaries */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px;
    
    &::after {
        background: url(image.jpg) 50%/ cover;
        content: ''
    }
}
```

**Step #2**: set the `transform-origin` on the pseudo to the middle of the bottom edge (`100% 50%`) - this ensures the bottom edge will remain in place after applying the 3D transform.

**Step #3**: apply a 3D skew along the `z` axis lengthening the edge along the `y` axis.

Yes, we don't have 3D skew functions in CSS. But we have `matrix3d()`, which can be used to express any rotation, scale, skew, translation!

So let's first understand how skewing works.

Skewing happens along an axis.

Here's an [interactive demo](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/full/JoQRdb) illustrating how the 2D skew functions work.

Consider this example, where we skew along the *x* axis and the edge along the *y* axis gets lengthened as the y axis rotates away from its initial position - this angle is the skew angle. The *z* axis is perpendicular onto the plane in which we skew (*xOy* in this example) and is unaffected:

[image: skewX example]

Well, in our case, we do something similar, but the skew happens in the *yOz* plane, not in the *xOy* plane, as we skew along the *z* axis instead of along the *x* axis.

[image: the system of coordinates]

Since we've anchored the middle of the bottom edge of our pseudo in place with `transform-origin` and this skew happens along the *z* axis (perpendicular onto the screen), it results we're basically pulling and stretching our pseudo back, towards the back of the screen, preserving the *x* and *y* coordinates of every point, but changing the *z* coordinates.

Basically, it would look like below if we were to view it in 3D without flattening into the parent's plane (the parent is bounded by the outline).

[image: 3D view at result post z-skew with no flattening into parent's plane]

You can see how the horizontal guidelines at the top show how the top of the skewed pseudo has preserved its *x* and *y* coordinates, it just got pulled back along the *z* axis.

Alright, how do we CSS this?

As mentioned, there's no 3D skew, but we can build our transform matrix ourselves. Since this is a skew along the *z* axis (3rd axis) stretching the edge along the *y* axis (2nd axis), the only position in our matrix different from the [unit matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) (`1` along the main diagonal, `0` elsewhere) is going to be on the 3rd row, 2nd column. And we're going to have the tangent of the skew angle there. On MDN, you can see this for `skewX()` and `skewY()` too.

This is because every point along the skew axis gets displaced by its coordinate along the lengthening axis times the tangent of the skew angle - you can see this in the first illustration if you draw parallels to the axes (*x* axis, *y* axis pre- and post-skew) through the example point in its original position (in grey) and final position (in black). Drawing these parallels creates a right triangle where the *x* displacement over the *y* coordinate is the tangent of the skew angle.

Okay, back to the matrix, it looks like this.

```
1   0    0
0   1    0
0 tan(a) 1
```

To get the `matrix3d()` values, we add one more row and one more column identical to what they'd be in a `4x4` unit matrix and then just list the values column by column (*not* row by row!). So far, we have:

```
@use 'sass:math'; // allows us to use trigonometric functions
$a: 60deg; // the skew angle

div {
    display: grid;
    width: 28em;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    perspective: 25em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px;
    
    &::after {
        transform-origin: 50% 100%;
        transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, /* 1st column */
                            0, 1, math.tan($a), 0, /* 2nd column */
                            0, 0, 1, 0, /* 3rd column */
                            0, 0, 0, 1);
        background: url(image.jpg) 50%/ cover;
        content: ''
    }
}
```

Note we've also added a `perspective` to get the distorted view (smaller at the top/ further back).

The code so far gives us the flattened version of what we can see in the gif above. And I say the flattened version because, with what we have here, the pseudo always gets flattened in the plane of its parent.

When the parent `div` has no 3D transform, we look at it from the front and the pseudo obviously looks flattened.

When the parent `div` does have a 3D transform, its 3D-transformed pseudo gets flattened into its plane because the default `transform-style` value is `flat`. This means that any 3D-transformed children/ pseudos of a 3D transformed parent get flattened in the plane of the parent. This can be changed if we set the div's `transform-style` to `preserve-3d`. But we don't want that here.

**Step 4**: fix the top edge!

There's just one more thing that still doesn't look right: the post-`transform` top edge is now below the original one.

[image: post-transform result]

This is because we've set a `perspective` and how this works. By default, the `perspective-origin` is dead in the middle of the element we set it on (in this case our `div`), at `50%` horizontally and `50%` vertically.

Let's consider just the points behind the plane of the screen because that's where our entire 3D-skewed pseudo is.

With the default `perspective-origin` (`50% 50%`), only the points on the line perpendicular onto the plane of the screen in the very middle of our `div` are going to be projected onto the screen plane at a point with the same *x,y* coordinates as their own after taking into account perspective. Only the points in the plane perpendicular onto the screen and intersecting the screen along the horizontal midline of the `div` are going to be projected onto this horizontal midline after taking into account perspective.

Do you see where this is going? If we move the `perspective-origin` so that it's in the middle of the div's top edge (`50% 0`), then the points in the plane perpendicular onto the screen along this top edge are going to be projected along this top edge - that is, the top edge of the 3D-skewed pseudo will be along the same line as its parent's top edge.

So our final code is:

```
@use 'sass:math'; // allows us to use trigonometric functions
$a: 60deg; // the skew angle

div {
    display: grid;
    width: 28em;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    perspective-origin: 50% 0;
    perspective: 25em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px;
    
    &::after {
        transform-origin: 50% 100%;
        transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, /* 1st column */
                            0, 1, math.tan($a), 0, /* 2nd column */
                            0, 0, 1, 0, /* 3rd column */
                            0, 0, 0, 1);
        background: url(image.jpg) 50%/ cover;
        content: ''
    }
}
```

Here is [a live comparative view](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/XWBMJjr/e4aa258a3b0b04633fd5ffff036facad) between our result and its pre-transform version as both divs rotate in 3D to show they're flat in the *xOy* plane.

[image: comparative view animation]

---

Don't want to use a preprocessor for the tangent value? Firefox and Safari support trigonometric functions by default already and Chrome 111+ supports them with the *Experimental Web Platform features* flag enabled in `chrome://flags`.

**Edit**: trigonometric functions in CSS now work cross-browser.

Don't want to wait for Chromium support either? You don't even need to use a tangent computation there, you can use any positive number - the bigger this number gets, the smaller the top edge gets. I used the tangent value to illustrate where it comes from, but you don't have to. Our tangent values are computed for angles from `0°` to `90°`. This gives us tangent values from `0` to `+Infinity`. So yeah, any positive number will do there in the matrix.